# Trouble setting up Neovim to autocomplete with neovim/nvim-lspconfig

Tags: lua, neovim

I've been trying to set up autocomplete for languages with `neovim/nvim-lspconfig`

This is the code I have so far:

```
set cot=menuone,noinsert shm+=c
let g:completion_matching_strategy_list = ['exact', 'substring', 'fuzzy']

nnoremap <leader>vd :lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>vi :lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>vsh :lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>vrr :lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>vrn :lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>vh :lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>vca :lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>vsd :lua vim.lsp.util.show_line_diagnostics(); vim.lsp.util.show_line_diagnostics()<CR>
command! -buffer -nargs=0 LspShowLineDiagnostics lua require'jumpLoc'.openLineDiagnostics()
nnoremap <buffer><silent> <C-h> <cmd>LspShowLineDiagnostics<CR>

:lua << EOF
  local nvim_lsp = require('lspconfig')
  local on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
    require('completion').on_attach()
  end
  local servers = {'clangd', 'pyright', 'gopls'}
  for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
    nvim_lsp[lsp].setup {
      on_attach = on_attach,
    }
  end
EOF
```

When I try to test them, I'm only able to get warning checks and syntax highlighting. I'm not able to get autocomplete to work. Does anyone know if I need to enable a setting or environment variable to enable this?

Comment: what autocomplete plugin are you using?

Comment: Completion-nvim is obsolete, please use [nvim-cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp) instead.

Answer (score -1):

yeah. your problem is that you `call` on_attach instead of `returning it`

this is the problem

```lua
  local on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
    require('completion').on_attach()
  end
```

change the above code to

```lua
  local on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
    return require('completion').on_attach
  end
```

and here:

```
    nvim_lsp[lsp].setup {
      on_attach = on_attach,
    }
```

you are parsing a `on_attach` function, you are not allowed to call it, you `pass the function object`

from the `completion-nvim` docs (https://github.com/nvim-lua/completion-nvim#setup):

```lua
lua require'lspconfig'.pyls.setup{on_attach=require'completion'.on_attach}
```

they pass the function, instead of calling it.

just try this example from `readme`, ok? and tell me the results